# "Не" или "ни" в предложении: "Что я только ни/не делал, однако помогло только это средство"?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Подскажите, пожалуйста, "не" или "ни" нужно писать в следующем предложении?По идее, это усиление и должно идти "ни", но сомневаюсь.

> Что я только ни/не делал, однако помогло только это средство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: **Что я только ни делал, однако помогло только это средство.**

Это СПП с придаточным уступительным, усилительная частица НИ, здесь нет отрицания.

Сравнить: **Что я только не делал!**

В простом восклицательном предложении используется частица НЕ, но смысл предложений тоже утвердительный.

Answer (score 1):

В исходном варианте не видно взаимосвязи двух частей предложения ("однако" мешает его целостному восприятию). Если же выделить из него независимое восклицание, получится "не":

> Чего я только **не** делал! Однако помогло мне только это средство.

Для сравнения. Прямое логическое противопоставление действий результату выражается с использованием усилительной частицы "ни":

> Что я **ни** делал, мне ничего не помогало, однако это средство помогло.
>
> Что бы я **ни** делал, помогло мне только это средство.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, предложение составлено "коряво", из-за этого трудно решить к какому правилу его отнести. Лучше бы выбрать одно из двух:

1. Что я не делал! Однако помогло мне только это средство.
2. Что я ни делал, помогло мне только это средство.

Исходное предложение все-таки, я думаю, является неудачным вариантом второго, поэтому пишем НИ.