# не и ни с глаголами

Tags: частица-не, глаголы

Какую частицу - "не" или "ни" - правильно будет употребить в предложении: "Сколько не смотрю, не могу налюбоваться".

Comment: Уже был похожий вопрос. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447680/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82

Answer (score 1):

***Сколько ни смотрю, не могу налюбоваться.***

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным уступительным.

Частица НИ относится к союзных словам: КТО НИ, КАК НИ, ГДЕ НИ и др.

Частица НИ у**силивает  утвердительный смысл** предложения (нет отрицания),  ее можно **изъять** из предложения без изменения смысла: *сколько  смотрю, не могу налюбоваться.*

Примеры:

***Куда ни обращаю взор***, кругом синеет мрачный бор и день права свои утратил.

*Не мог он ямба от хорея, **как мы ни бились**, отличить.*

Comment: Спасибо, Галина. Всё очень доступно и понятно. Удач и всех благ.